# Finding index of the maximum value of cube(3d array) using Armadillo library in C++

Tags: c++

I am using Armadillo library for the matrix calculation in C++.

And I have one question about finding an index of the maximum value of given 3d arrays.

I found on their website about index_max().

index_max( M, dim )

dim=0, return a row vector, with each column containing the index of the extremum value in the corresponding column of M

dim=1, return a column vector, with each row containing the index of the extremum value in the corresponding row of M

And it seems like, they return the index of the maximum value of each row and column.

But I need an index of the maximum value of the entire matrix.

Does anyone know any way to find an index of the max using Armadillo library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the standalone [index_max()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#index_min_and_index_max_standalone) function, use the [.index_max()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#index_min_and_index_max_member) member function of the matrix or cube. Example:

```
arma::mat X(100, 200, arma::fill::randu);

arma::uword index = X.index_max();
```

Comment: But it doesn't look like it also works for cube...?

Comment: Oh, I think it also works for 3d. So this returns the linear index which means that if the max value of 3*3 matrix is at 3nd row & 3nd column, it gives me 8. Right?

Comment: You can verify this using `double max_val = X(index)`.